# NSURL is either null or a confusing string

Tags: iphone, nsurl

i have a url with some "special" characters in it like quotes.
When i try this:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://someurl/%22sometext%22"];
```

the url is null.

When i try this:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[@"http://someurl/%22sometext%22" stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

i geht a horrible output like this:

{type = 15, string = http://someurl/%22sometext%22, encoding = 134217984, base = (null)}

Can anybody help me please?

Comment: what's problem in first url? its work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't encode it yourself before.. e.g. `NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString: [@"http://someurl/\"sometext\"" stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding]];` is working.

But for proper URL Encoding use other functions:

```
- (NSString*) encodeString: (NSString*) string
{
    NSString* result = (NSString*) CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(kCFAllocatorDefault, (CFStringRef)string, NULL, CFSTR("% '\"?=&+<>;:-"), kCFStringEncodingUTF8);
    return [result autorelease];
}
```